# Where to find mcr_root on macOS to run compiled MATLAB program?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to build a standalone executable for a MATLAB function on macOS 11.1. I'm using MATLAB_R2019a.

1. Compile the function `cli.m` and write to `build-binary`

```
mcc -m -R -singleCompThread -R -nodisplay -R -nojvm cli.m -d build-binary
```

2. Try running `./build-binary/run_cli.sh` and get the following error

```
Usage:
./run_cli.sh <deployedMCRroot> args
```

I installed the MATLAB runtime by downloading it from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/matlab-runtime.html) and running

```
./install -mode silent -agreeToLicense yes
```

But I have no idea where it installed to or what to pass into `<deployedMCRroot>`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that if you hadn't passed `-mode silent` when installing, the installer would have told you where it installed the MCR. :)

Comment: Did you look under `/Applications/`? Also, you can pass your MATLAB root directory as the MCR, you don't need to install the MCR if you have MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks - it turns out I hadn't correctly installed the MCR.